# SQL finding records in multiple columns based on the records in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a trouble with following task.

I have a view that shows me BOM structure - viewBOMsApprRevisions:

```
PartNumL1 PartNumL2 PartNumL3 PartNumL4 PartNumL5
```

and I have a table that consist selected PartNum - 17 records,

What I want to do is list all the records from the view where PartNum (17 records) exist.

I know how to do that with a single record

```
SELECT *
FROM viewBOMsApprRevisions 
WHERE '11614' in (PartNumL1,PartNumL2,PartNumL3, PartNumL4, PartNumL5)
```

But I can't figure out how to use list of records from another table.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You have to provide some schema (`SHOW CREATE tableName`)

Comment: If you want to get records from your view where a value in another table exists in one of the columns then you'd just add a join in between your from and where to the other table, change your Where to an On and change '11614' to the column name from the other table. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements, you need a basic [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Since you didn't provide your table schema, here's a generic example:

```
SELECT        *
FROM          Table1
INNER JOIN    Table2 ON Table2.SomeKey = Table1.SomeKey
WHERE         '11614' IN(Table2.PartNumber)
```

Comment: I think you want to move the `WHERE` clause

Comment: @bluefeet, lol. That's what I get for eating a spicy salad **while** writing SQL...

Comment: Really, that filtering (`WHERE` clause) condition should (and depending on optimizer, may be anyways) be made part of the `JOIN` condition.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, let's not criticize a sample query, intended to point someone in the right direction, created with little to no requirements, and no understanding of the table schema...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM viewBOMsApprRevisions 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * from Partnum 
              WHERE Partnum.Partnumber in (PartNumL1,PartNumL2,PartNumL3,
                                           PartNumL4, PartNumL5))
```

Comment: Ross, Thank you very much, that's exactly what I wanted to get. Much appreciated.